# Why Should we compile our css and js files in laravel? what benefits it has?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, laravel-mix

I am new to Vue, in one of videos on internet they Compile their assets, i am wonder that why should we compile our assets? second can we use Vue and Vue-router without compiling the assets in laravel? if yes how?

Comment: Why you should not compile is there a benefit on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way to achieve that is loading both vue and vue-router from cnd, but I strongly recomend use npm, when your project is growing always its better have compiled everting.

Comment: so can we use Vue without compiling those assets in laravel?

Comment: sure, but belive me, It's way better compiling.